# C++ container to store(insert/get/remove) structure with multi key of integer value is pointer

Tags: c++, dictionary, queue

How to store following structure 
Key=[k1,k2,...,kn]; Value=void*
n is unknown at compile time. It's constant for object but varies for class.
It must be like tree but C++ STL. It must be as fast as it can be for inserting, removing and getting.
I think it must be map[integer, map[integer, ... map[integer, void*]...]] but I can't understand how to implement it with unknown level "n".

It's used for "queue", where items can insert in unknown order, but it must be dequeued in right order 1,1,1 then 1,1,2, .... 1,1,V3max, 1,2,1, ...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by having that kind of structure?

Comment: It's custom protocol that have numbered packets. Numbering is multilevel. 
For example, packets processed in levels: Transport Level|Session Level|Application Level; each packet contains number and packet's count for this level: ex. 1/1000|1/10|1/1. UDP cannot transfer it in right order, so first packet can be received after second. This structure can help to store packets and other subsystem can ask packets in right order and wait "right" packets not discarding others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple structure like this:

```
struct MyType
{
  std::string name;
  std::map<int, MyType> mA;
};
```

Then create a root map that accept MyType identified by a key

```
std::map<int, MyType> mRootMap;
```

Then you can add like this (for simplicity, no recursivity)

```
MyType a;
MyType b;
MyType c;
c.name = "This is C";
b.mA[789] = c;
a.mA[456] = b;
mRootMap[123] = a;
```

Then you could access like this

```
std::cout << mRootMap[123].mA[456].mA[789].name << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
This is C
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just thinking about such a decision, but could not formalize and implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `std::vector<int>` with an `operator<` and an `operator==` as a key.

```
bool operator<(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
    {
        // decide what to do
    }

    for (std::vector<int>::size_type index = 0 ; index < a.size() ; ++index)
    {
        if (a[index] < b[index])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool operator==(const std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I think it is slow. It can be replaced with "ordered" vector<struct {vector<int>, void*}> where struct have operators < and ==. But tests are required.

Comment: Well, since the `std::vector<int>`s are the keys, they are ordered in the map/set and search is done by dichotomy, only the first key elements being tested in most cases.